# Axie infinity battle’s logs

Tags: logging, blockchain, ethereum, erc20

How can I get all battle’s logs of all players from game Axie Infinity which based on ethereum. I need it for developing strategy for my battle.
For example: on Axie.zone you can see link of another player battle.
Link for example: https://cdn.axieinfinity.com/game/deeplink.html?f=rpl&q=8802e318-61ce-47c8-9ac1-764e977c1b17
Thanks for any help!